# Processing every file from a list of folders

Tags: bash

I have a folder structure like

```
base
|
|---rbbc_23434
|    |------rbbp_34954
|    |        |___this.json
|
|---rbbc_222334
|    |------rbbp_39884954
|    |        |___this.json
|
etc
```

And I want to process each `this.json`. Notice that the letters after rbbp are random

I have the following

```
#! /bin/bash

search_dir=/path/to/base/

bf="$(basename -- $search_dir)"

for entry in "$search_dir"*/
do
    #echo "$entry"
    f="$(basename -- $entry)"
    echo "$f"
    if [[ "$f" == "rbb"* ]]
    then
         echo "$entry"
         ls "$entry""rbbp"*"/this.json"
         #echo "$entry""rdgp"*"/this2.json"

         #python3 something.py --input "$entry""rbbp"*"/this.json" 
         
    fi
done
```

With `ls` I can localize the `this.json` files from all folders but these wildcards do not seem to work when specifying a file for input to a python script or even echo

How can I specify this `this.json` file as a path to the `something.py` script?

Comment: There's no `rdgp` in any of your directory names. Is that supposed to be `rbbp`?

Comment: yes sorry it is a typo

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the nested loops and `if` statements, just make a wildcard that matches all the directories in the path.

```
search_dir=/path/to/base
for file in "$search_dir"/rbb*/rbbp*/this.json
do
    python3 something.py --input "$file"
done
```